# copy worksheet to different workbook with same worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vba, and have looked extensively to answer my question.  I have 3 workbooks with 3 worksheets with the same name. The workbooks are Database, Sample_Request and Sample_List.  In theory, when someone request a sample they open the Sample_Request book (which copies data from the Database file) creates a record of sample request and mails it to the folks to fulfill request.  Then the folks fulfilling request open the Sample_List book to log the information.  This file also copies data from the Database file. When request is fulfilled and before the Sample_List file is closed, the key data is copied from the Sample_List book to the Database.  However, the code indicates an error and does not copy the information.
Here is the code when opening the Sample_List file:

```
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
On Error GoTo line1
Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleList").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestLists").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserLists").Unprotect Password:="pass"
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("Databasev1.xlsm")
wbk2.Sheets("TestLists").Range("A1:AZ500").Copy Destination:=Workbooks      ("Sample_listv1.xlsm").Sheets("TestLists").Range("A1:AZ500")
wbk2.Sheets("UserLists").Range("A1:AE500").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Sample_listv1.xlsm").Sheets("UserLists").Range("A1:AE500")
wbk2.Sheets("SampleList").Range("A1:AL100000").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Sample_listv1.xlsm").Sheets("SampleList").Range("A:AL")

wbk2.Close False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleList").Protect Password:="pass"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestLists").Protect Password:="pass"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserLists").Protect Password:="pass"

Then when getting ready to close this is the code I use:

    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
On Error GoTo line1
    Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserLists").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(“Databasev1.xlsm”)
        wbk2.Worksheets("UserLists").Unprotect Password:="pass"
    wbk1.Sheets("UserLists").Range("A1:AE500").Copy Destination:=Workbooks(“Databasev1.xlsm”).Sheets("UserLists").Range("A1:AE500")
        wbk2.Worksheets("UserLists").Protect Password:="pass"

    wbk2.Close False

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserLists").Protect Password:="pass"
```

NOTE: Both codes are located in differing userforms, that I have called using the UIeditor.
What am I not doing or doing wrong?

Comment: Workbook("name").Sheets("name').Copy After:=Workbook("name2").Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count) would copy a sheet to another workbook.  Unsure what your question is beyond how to VBA perform that routine.

Comment: Won't your routine create an additional worksheet (name (2)) in the database?  The database sheet names also need to remain the same as multiple folks will access either requesting or documenting the request.

Comment: Well I figured as soon as I posted this I'd find the right code to work - and I did.  Basically I created a macro and recorded the steps to copy it.  I copied the macro back into my vba code and all is great.